# Flutter | Info.plist | Found Non-Key Inside <dict> about BGTaskSchedulePermittedIdentifiers key

Tags: swift, xcode, flutter

I'm trying to build my app with Xcode, but I am faced with:

> non key inside dict line 52

What’s the problem with line 52? I can’t find a solution.

Here are my XML lines:

```xml
<key>BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers</key>
    <array>

        <string></string>
    </array>
</key>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the last reference to `</key>`. It's going to be something like this:

```xml
<key>BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers</key>
    <array>

        <string></string>
    </array>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How did it come here :)